# Is it possible to extend the EventTarget interface?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I'm looking for an answer if this is possible, or even a good idea.

Usually, as a fix for IE8 and earlier versions, a workaround similar to this is used:

```
var addEvent = function(obj, e, cb) {
    if(obj.attachEvent) {
        return obj.attachEvent('on' + e, cb);
    } else {
        obj.addEventListener(e, cb, false);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and then the programmer would always use `addEvent` instead of `addEventListener`.

Is there any way or point to create an `addEventListener` function that would wrap around the `attachEvent` when it is undefined?

I imagine it's a bit tricky since the EventTarget can be a DOM element, the document, or the window, or somethign else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how far back you want to go. On IE8, you can extend `Element.prototype` to add features to all HTML elements, which is 90% at least of the work. I'm fairly sure you can't do that in IE6 (PrototypeJS had to resort to extending individual `Element` instances), I don't remember about IE7. Unless you're targeting east-Asian markets, you can basically ignore IE7 and earlier, though.

Here's an example of how you do that:

```
(function() {
  // Functions for IE
  function stopPropagation() {
    this.cancelBubble = true;
  }
  function preventDefault() {
    this.returnValue = false;
  }
  function addEventUsingAttach(eventName, handler)
  {
    this.attachEvent("on" + eventName, function() {
      var e = window.event;
      e.stopPropagation = stopPropagation;
      e.preventDefault = preventDefault;
      handler.call(this, e);
    });
  }

  // Function to add `addEvent` to the given target object
  function extendIt(target)
  {
    if (target.addEventListener) {
      target.addEvent = Element.prototype.addEventListener;
    }
    else {
      target.addEvent = addEventUsingAttach;
    }
  }

  // Add it to `Element.prototype` if we have it
  if (typeof Element !== "undefined" &&
      typeof Element.prototype !== "undefined") {
    extendIt(Element.prototype);
  }

  // Add it to `window` and `document` (etc.)
  extendIt(window);
  extendIt(document);
})();
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/IgaCaYIm/3) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/IgaCaYIm/3/edit)

Then you manually extend the other EventTargets, like `window` and `document` (see the end of the code listing above).

---

**Original answer**: I originally misread your question to be about adding `addEventListener`, specifically, on IE8, whereas in fact your question is quite clearly **not** about adding that, but adding your own `addEvent`. I'm leaving this answer in place for other readers:

It depends on how far back you want to go. On IE8, you can extend `Element.prototype` to add `addEventListener` to it, and that will be used by all HTML elements on the page (see below). The shim you add can't support the capturing phase, though, because IE didn't support it until they supported `addEventListener` natively. I'm fairly sure you can't extend `Element.prototype` on earlier versions (IE7, IE6), PrototypeJS had to fall back to extending specific elements for older versions of IE. But it works in IE8.

Having extended `Element.prototype`, then you'd have to manually extend the other event targets you mentioned, but extending `Element.prototype` does most of the work.

But if you do this and you include third-party scripts, beware that they may assume a correct implementation of `addEventListeneer` complete with the capturing phase.

Here's a basic shim for adding `addEventListener` to IE8:

```
(function() {
  function stopPropagation() {
    this.cancelBubble = true;
  }
  function preventDefault() {
    this.returnValue = false;
  }
  if (typeof Element !== "undefined" &&
      typeof Element.prototype !== "undefined" &&
      !Element.prototype.addEventListener) {
    Element.prototype.addEventListener = function(eventName, handler, useCapture) {
      if (useCapture) {
        throw "Browser doesn't support capturing phase";
      }
      this.attachEvent("on" + eventName, function() {
        var e = window.event;
        e.stopPropagation = stopPropagation;
        e.preventDefault = preventDefault;
        handler.call(this, e);
      });
    };
  }
})();
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/IgaCaYIm/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/IgaCaYIm/1/edit)

Comment: Actually T.J. I did originally mean that I could just include something like your script for IE8 (and I am completely for ignoring versions prior to it), and then use `addEventListener` normally (without capturing in IE8). The point was to avoid using a distinctively named addEvent, and instead standards based vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, functions can be added to an object by attaching the function to the object

```
obj.addEventListener = function(/* args*/) { /* body */ }
```

or by attaching the function to the prototype of the object constuctor

```
EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function(/* args*/) { /* body */ }
```

With the former, the added function can be called on the particular object only, while the latter lets you call the function on all objects that where or will be created from that particular object constuctor.

However,

- EventTargets are host objects and therefore it is implementation dependant whether functions can be added to such objects.
- EventTargets are host objects and therefore it is implementation dependant whether `EventTarget.prototype` actually exists and has the same meaning as with native objects.
- If an object adheres to the `EventTarget` interface, it most likely already has an `addEventListener` function.
- The event listener attached with `attachEvent` has different arguments than the one added with `addEventListener`.

In the end, it is not feasable to try and make a browser with crappy DOM support more standards complient using JavaScript.

Comment: `typeof EventTarget` is `"undefined"` even on Chrome, much less IE8.