# EventTarget interface in safari

Tags: javascript, safari, webkit

I started to extend the `EventTarget` interface by adding some useful `prototypes` but then I tested it on Safari 8 and get :

```
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: EventTarget
```

I found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) that *"`window.EventTarget` does not exist"* for Safari.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616538/is-it-possible-to-extend-the-eventtarget-interface) looks really interesting but it's about IE8.

So, I want to know if **a reference to the EventTarget interface is accessible on Safari**, or a workaround to use code like `EventTarget.prototype.hasEventListener` and `EventTarget.prototype.hasEventListener` without getting any errors on Safari ?

**Edit**
I found an interesting [commit](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/189660) which says that it was implemented the 09/12/15 (from timestamp), but it sure doesn't work in Safari 9.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Workaround :

I simply used the [`Element` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) as a fallback for Safari

```
var EventTarget = EventTarget || Element;
EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function(){/*Some magic here*/};
```

I also checked that Element inherits `prototypes` from the EventTarget interface and it does ! (`document.body.addEventListener == EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener` returned `true`)

Comment: If I do that when extending EventTarget, I still get: "Illegal constructor". It seems that extending from EventTarget only works in chrome.

Comment: Wich Safari version are you using and what's the case where you use it ?

Comment: I use `class Car extends EventTarget {}` and then `let c = new Car()` and then `c.addEventListener()`. This works in Chrome but in safari the constructor is not allowed to extend from EventTarget :(

Comment: In Safari 9 that's not even possible to use Element as a constructor (even it is !). As I didn't updated to the newest version I can't do more research about that case but you can look at [this compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget#Browser_compatibility)  to see that Safari got the ``EventTarget`` support from 10.1 but not as a ``constructor``. That could mean that var ``EventTarget = EventTarget || Element`` results to the integrated ``EventTarget`` and explain why you can't make ``new something()`` with it !

Comment: Yeah that's super annoying. I'd like to emit events from anything that I want, not just DOM elements.

Comment: Safari 14 now supports `EventTarget` as a constructor, see more in the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-14-release-notes).

Comment: @J.RyanStinnett yes they didi, 4 years and a half later haha (Thanks for letting us know though )

Answer (score 3):

Safari just doesn't allow you to use the `EventTarget` interface in your own objects other than DOM elements. So I simply replicated the class to do it.

```
class EventDispatcher {

    constructor() {
        this._listeners = [];
    }

    hasEventListener(type, listener) {
        return this._listeners.some(item => item.type === type && item.listener === listener);
    }

    addEventListener(type, listener) {
        if (!this.hasEventListener(type, listener)) {
            this._listeners.push({type, listener, options: {once: false}});
        }
        // console.log(`${this}-listeners:`,this._listeners);
        return this
    }

    removeEventListener(type, listener) {
        let index = this._listeners.findIndex(item => item.type === type && item.listener === listener);
        if (index >= 0) this._listeners.splice(index, 1);
//        console.log(`${this}-listeners:`, this._listeners);
        return this;
    }

    removeEventListeners() {
        this._listeners = [];
        return this;
    }

    dispatchEvent(evt) {
        this._listeners
            .filter(item => item.type === evt.type)
            .forEach(item => {
                const {type, listener, options: {once}} = item;
                listener.call(this, evt);
                if (once === true) this.removeEventListener(type, listener)
            });
        // console.log(`${this}-listeners:`,this._listeners);
        return this
    }
}
```