# How to add an alias for 'addEventListener' method?

Tags: javascript, alias, event-listener

It's common in many libraries to use `on` rather than `addEventListener`. Personally I find it quite annoying to type `addEventListener` every time.

Is there a way to add an alias?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to other answers, I end up with this:

```
EventTarget.prototype.on = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener
```

I found in [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) that `addEventListener` method belongs to `EventTarget`, so that's the right object to add an alias.

Comment: P.s. I found that `EventTarget` is not supported on older Safari.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Here is a possible work around for that, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36679639/465590

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create just an alias, you can add a new reference of the `addEventListener` method to a brand new `on` method like this:

```
Node.prototype.on = Node.prototype.addEventListener
```

Comment: Thanks, it's just what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Taking jQuery as an example, `on` is not an alias. It is a wrapper function around `addEventListener` (internally, `on` calls the `jQuery.event.add` function, which in turn calls `addEventListener`). The approach will be similar in other libraries.

As Nhor pointed out, you can create a new function pointing to `addEventListener`, but the semantics will be different than in most libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `on` as an alias for `Element.addEventListener` as below

```
Element.prototype.on = Element.prototype.addEventListener
```